# How do I modify the height and width of the PDF being show in `react-pdf` using tailwind?

Tags: javascript, pdf, tailwind-css, react-pdf

I'm trying to render a PDF through `react-pdf` to a certain width and height. How can I do this by using Tailwind classes? In the screenshot attached, you can see that the PDF is so much bigger than one of the components, which is the same component I want it to be the same size of. [image]

Here's the code I'm currently using for the PDF render:

```
<>
<Document file={pdfUrl}>
            <Page
                pageNumber={1}
                className="h-24 w-10 border-solid border-2 border-sky-500"
            />
        </Document>
<>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to solved this by instead rendering it the first page as an image and not the whole PDF and then using a `canvas` to show the first page:

```
function ImagePreview({ pdf, containerWidth, containerHeight }) {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function init() {
            try {
                const canvas = canvasRef.current;
                const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                const uid = await getUserId();
                const publicUrl = await supabase.storage.from("pdf-documents").getPublicUrl(uid + "/" + pdf.name).data.publicUrl;

                // Load the PDF file
                pdfjsLib
                    .getDocument(publicUrl)
                    .promise.then((pdf) => {
                        // Get the specified page
                        return pdf.getPage(1);
                    })
                    .then((page) => {
                        // Set the canvas dimensions to match the PDF page dimensions
                        const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1 });
                        const canvasWidth = containerWidth;
                        const canvasHeight = containerHeight;
                        const scaleX = canvasWidth / viewport.width;
                        const scaleY = canvasHeight / viewport.height;
                        const scale = Math.max(scaleX, scaleY);
                        const newViewport = page.getViewport({ scale });

                        // Set the canvas dimensions to match the fixed size
                        canvas.width = canvasWidth;
                        canvas.height = canvasHeight;

                        // Render the PDF page as an HTML5 canvas
                        const renderContext = {
                            canvasContext: ctx,
                            viewport: newViewport,
                        };
                        page.render(renderContext);
                    });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }

        init();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
        </div>
    );
}
```